# Python-How to see the actual Ms-SQL query fired

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I know for MySQL and Postgres but not for MsSQL? how do I do that?

Upon

```
cursor.execute("insert into data_AutoScale_DELHUB(AWB_Number,Weight,Length,Width,Height,Customer_Name,Scan_Time,Series_Flag) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" , data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7])
print cursor.query
```

it returns `'pyodbc.Cursor' object has no attribute 'query'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way do go, but maybe the simplest. Just print your query before execution.

queryTxt = "insert into bla bla bla"

print queryTxt

cursor.execute(queryTxt)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to also get the values (inserted) into your string.

I would suggest creating a function (maybe `verboseQuery()`) like the following:

```
def verboseQuery(query, *data):
    # See if the data matches up
    if(len(data) == query.count('?')):
        count = 0
        while(count != len(data)):
            # Replace the first occurrence of '?' with the first data point
            query = query.replace('?', str(data[count]), 1)
            count += 1

    # If the data did not match the query, return the original query,
    # otherwise, return the query we modified earlier
    return query
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
query = verboseQuery("insert into data_AutoScale_DELHUB(AWB_Number,Weight,Length,Width,Height,Customer_Name,Scan_Time,Series_F ag) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" , data[0],data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7])
print query
cursor.execute(query)
```

Which would print: (if `data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`)

```
insert into data_AutoScale_DELHUB(AWB_Number,Weight,Length,Width,Height,Customer_Name,Scan_Time,Series_F ag) VALUES (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```